# What will be the best Android layout or Canvas or SurfaceView, or Cocos2d android?

Tags: android

I am planning to make treasure hunt game which will contain particles effect,animation, Pinch Zoom  or double tap Zoom and Scrolling. What will be the best to work with treasure hunt game. I mean smooth zoom , nice particle etc .. and also resources or some example because I am new to android this will be learning process for me. So what should I choose to go ahead with ?

Suggestions with reason will be appreciated because I need to know why canvas not or surfaceview or cocos2d not.

Comment: From the FAQ: *"What kind of questions should I not ask here?"* - *"Questions where every answer is equally valid: “What’s your favorite ______?”"*. "Whats the best X" is highly subjective and can't be reasonably answered. You didn't even specify any criteria. The best? FPS wise? Easy api? Fast results? Great community support? And so on. StackOverflow is not the right place for this kind of question.

Comment: @alextsc  :  I mentioned from zoom in and zoom out point of view

Comment: @alextsc :  I guess as a beginner its a proper question to stack overflow nothing wrong in that i can see ? I have mentioned it properly that it should contain smooth zoom , and resources to understand

Comment: The rules are the same for everybody here, whether you are a programming beginner with no reputation or a veteran with 100k rep. Subjective questions are never ok here because they lead to pointless discussions. Every answer to a question here should be sortable in one of the two buckets "correct" and "wrong". This doesn't work for subjective questions, people will debate for ages and you won't have any better idea because you don't know who to believe. These rules are not in place to scare you away, they are here to prevent unconstructive discussions. *(and zoom can be done with any afaik)*

Comment: @alextsc : thanks dude ... I will keep in mind from next time .. I tried android layout but I faced lot of problem for Zooming and scrollable ... I have to zoom the background of layout and that layout has many Imageviews. I have put that question in proper manner see if u can answer me on that ...and thanks a lot ... and m sorry too

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'd suggest you to use a SurfaceView, because you needn't work with Layouts and XML Files, so it's faster than a custom Custom View or Android Layout, because of it's hardwarenearness.
SurfaceView is also the most common way to draw in games, so you'll find many tutorials on this in the internet()([for example the well done Droidnova tutorial](http://www.droidnova.com/2d-tutorial-series-part-ii,772.html)).

It should be possible to recognize gestures with the abstract Surface View class onTouchEvent.

There are also some game engines, which are easy to use and sometimes even have a good performance, but they are often bad documentated and debugging is hard, if you doesn't know the underlying source code, so I wouldn't suggest them.